# постинг на Фейсбуке - настроить права приложения

Tags: facebook, facebook-api, facebooksdk, facebook-graph-api

Привет всем!

Требуется подсказка по постингу на странице в фейсбуке. Использую Facebook SDK (пробовал php и js, настраивал через curl и т.п.) проблема с permissions (правами приложения на публикацию).

Возвращает ошибку:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#200) Permissions error","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"{code}"}}
```

В Facebook обращался - есть ответ:

```
Вашему приложению не нужны разрешения manage_pages или publish_pages, чтобы публиковать записи на Страницах или в блогах, администратором которых вы являетесь. Поскольку вы являетесь администратором приложения, у вас уже есть необходимые разрешения и вы можете публиковать записи в своей Хронике или на странице, которой вы управляете.
```

Если кто-то решил такую проблему, подскажите, что можно сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел проблему, возможно кому-нибудь понадобится: на фейсбуке в большой набор access_token'ов. 
Для публикации требуется генерация правильного токена-маркера здесь 
 https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/  
они похожи, но всякий раз генерируется новый, поэтому нужно выбирать правильный маркер. Генерация ключа проходит в 3 этапа: генерируется маркер приложения (предполагаем, что вы правильно выбрали приложение), затем на его основе генерируется маркер страницы (если вы публикуете для сообщества), далее генерируете маркер с правом публикации в сообществе.
 
При этом маркер имеет ограниченный срок действия (.../docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension). Обратите внимание, что маркер для PHP SDK генерируется всего на пару часов и вам потребуется перегенерация маркера на длительный срок: 60 дней.(для JS SDK и мобильных приложений срок действия маркера - как описывают в статье - устанавливается сразу на 60 дней). 
Обращаю внимание, что генерация маркера длительного срока действия для PHP производится на сервере (из строки запроса браузера у вас не получится его сгенерировать).

```
<?php

$access_token = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={app-id}&client_secret={app-secret}&fb_exchange_token={short-term-token}');

echo $access_token;
```

Теперь ваш токен готов, с этим токеном можно публиковать на странице от имени страницы.

На ВК этот фокус устроен гораздо проще.

Answer (score 0):

Ну действительно не нужны права, вы просто должны быть авторизованы. Права наверно нужны для публикации через API. Вот простая кнопка на сайте для публикации, например ссылки на этот сайт.

`<li class="share-facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=Здесь_должен_быть_текст_публикации"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a></li>`

Comment: share идет для распространения ссылок и делается вручную через вход пользователя - это простая задача. У меня идет публикация от  имени приложения на странице (при необходимости автоматическая публикация - без авторизации).